# setup zlib to generate gzipped data

Tags: gzip, zlib

I have a question about using zlib library for compressing data. 
I want to setup zlib (namely deflateInit function) in such a way that the compressed data is binary equal to the data generated by command: gzip -9. Is this possible? 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 11):

windowsBits argument's default value is 15.
Adding 16 to it will be 31.
15 | 16 returns 31.

```
z_stream strm;
unsigned char* in = DATA TO COMPRESS;

strm.zalloc = Z_NULL;
strm.zfree = Z_NULL;
strm.opaque = Z_NULL;
strm.next_in = in;

int windowsBits = 15;
int GZIP_ENCODING = 16;

deflateInit2 (&strm, Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION, Z_DEFLATED,
              windowsBits | GZIP_ENCODING,
              8,
              Z_DEFAULT_STRATEGY));
```

http://www.lemoda.net/c/zlib-open-write/index.html

Answer (score 3):

You cannot get exactly the same output as gzip.  You can however get output that is compatible with gzip, so that gzip will be able to decompress it.  You need to use `deflateInit2()`.

Comment: I'm struggling with this same issue. I found the zlib FAQ (written by you, apparently) that explains the same solution-- use deflateInit2(). However, based on the extensive documentation for deflateInit2, it's still not obvious to me how to ask zlib to produce gzip-compatible data. 'strategy' seems the most likely parameter to tweak. Can you clarify please? I also tried forging a gzip header and footer but I wasn't able to fool 'gunzip'.

Comment: The documentation is in zlib.h.  Are you reading that?  It's all there in plain english.  It says under `deflateInit2`: _"windowBits can also be greater than 15 for optional gzip encoding.  Add 16 to windowBits to write a simple gzip header and trailer around the compressed data instead of a zlib wrapper."_

Comment: Okay, I see that now. So, if I'm reading that correcting, windowBits should be between 8-15, with 16 added if it's to be wrapped in gzip. I tried calling deflateInit2() with windowBits of 15+16 but it returns a stream error (-2). Note that the program is correctly producing zlib data using deflateInit()/deflate().

Comment: Please post a question with your code.  There are many reasons to return Z_STREAM_ERROR.

Comment: Thanks for your help and patience on this. I am going to hammer at this some more since there are a lot of factors in play-- it's an obscure embedded platform and the SDK I'm using has a rather old version of zlib. I'm going to try some things like making sure the code works on a modern desktop with modern zlib and upgrading zlib (+SDK) on the platform.